# Angularjs compare two objects in ng-options

Tags: angularjs

I have two arrays of objects. 
A very simplified example:

```
$scope.genres = [
    {
      id: '123',
      name: 'Genre 1'
    },
    {
      id: '124',
      name: 'Genre 2'
    },
    {
      id: '125',
      name: 'Genre 3'
    }
  ];

  $scope.selectedGenres = [{
      id: '123',
      name: 'Genre 1'
    }];
```

I use **genres** to populate a select.

```
<select style="height: 100px; width: 100%;"
                        multiple
                        ng-model="selectedGenres"
                        ng-options="option as option.name for option in genres"></select>
```

I realise doing: `$scope.selectedGenres = [$scope.genres[0]];`
Would work as the objects reference is the same.

Is there any way to compare the two objects for equality rather than their reference?

Example: http://jsbin.com/cizuyitadu/6/edit

Comment: what would the use case be that you can't match by reference?

Comment: I have an API. One call returns $scope.genres and the other returns $scope.selectedGenres.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your example your objects don't have the same properties so they are not going to be equal when using angular.equals.  Your selectedGenres object has a '$$hashKey' property on it (angular adds this) because you're not a specifying tracking property.  The objects in your $scope.genres array don't have the '$$hashKey' property.   That's why angular.equals is returning false.

If you add a track by property in your ng-options expression it will fix the issue.

```
ng-options="option as option.name for option in genres track by option.id"
```

Answer (score 7):

Add the following to your ng-options "track by option.id"

```
<select style="height: 100px; width: 100%;"
                    multiple
                    ng-model="selectedGenres"
                    ng-options="option as option.name for option in genres track by option.id"></select>
```

That will automatically select that option. That works in your example, and I presume that is what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

`angular.equals` is probably what you're looking for:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.equals

Comment: i tried that in demo by adding `console.log(angular.equals($scope.selectedGenres,$scope.genres[0]));` ... returns false